# MVC Site not working when published to web hosting provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I am trying to publish an MVC site.  The website/application are both setup for .NET Framework 4.  When the site is published, the MVC page gives the following error:

"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Also if I try to bring up a test aspx file, I get this error:

"The resource cannot be found."

The first test I perform is to delete the web.config.  At this point, I attempt to bring up an MVC page again and same error is displayed:

"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

However, if I try to bring up a test aspx page now, I actually get the page:

1 + 2 = 3

The test aspx page just contains this:

```
<html>
<body>
1 + 2 = <%=(1+2).ToString() %>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help of what to check next would be appreciated.  Saw similar threads where it mentions of adding:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

and

```
<asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
```

But that still gives me the same error when bringing up a MVC page.  Any help on how to proceed next to fix this MVC site would be appreciated.  Thanks.

**Update #1**

I did a search for the keyword "routes.MapRoute" in the entire project and found it only once in the RouteConfig.cs:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

The page I am testing is:

```
http://.../Home/Index
```

This is the page that returns:

"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem!  The problem was that the website hosting provider had the website setup for IIS 6.0.  In that case there are two options:

- Update hosting site to support IIS 7.0.  This was my solution and solved the problem
- Set the MapRoute to run a "fake" aspx page: (only do this if you cant update hosting to IIS 7.0):

  // IIS 6.0
  routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "typehereanything.aspx/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );

Using this second method is not recommended since now you have to plug in "typehereanything.aspx" into every URL: http://.../typehereanything.aspx/Home/Index

Any of those two options solved the issue.